# Extend UserProvider for FOS UserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.1

I am building a site using Symfony2 and it will be a white-label type of site, where multiple domains map to the same server.  So coolsite.customer1.com and aservice.customer2.com would map to the same site, but would need to appear different to the end user.  I already solved for the domains, and loading the unique configurations as a service.

With the FOS UserBundle setup and running with a custom user (that has the domain_id stored in it), registration, login, etc works fine except that users from domain1 can login to domain2 also.  This is expected in the FOS UserBundle.  I need to make modifications to the bundle so that it only will authenticate users on the domain they are assigned to.

I have created a userProvider that extends the original userProvider in FOS and have overridden the loadUserByUsername method to also check the domain.  See below:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Security\UserProvider as FOSProvider;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use Me\CoreBundle\Models\Core;

class UserProvider extends FOSProvider {

    /**
     *
     * @var ContainerInterface 
     */
    protected $container;


    public function __construct(UserManagerInterface $userManager, ContainerInterface $container) {
        parent::__construct($userManager);
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $core = $this->container->get('me_core');
        /* @var $core Core */

        $user = $this->findUserBy(array(
            'username'=>$username,
            'domain_id'=>$core->getDomainMap()->getId(),
        ));

        if (!$user) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username));
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function findUserBy(array $criteria) {
        return $this->userManager->findUserBy($criteria);
    }

}
```

I have configured the service with the following.

```
services:
  me.security.authentication.userprovider:
    class:  Me\UserBundle\Security\UserProvider
    arguments:
      - @fos_user.user_manager
      - @service_container
```

My security.yml looks like this:

```
security:
    providers:
        me.security.authentication.userprovider:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/_wdt, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/public, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

What happens when I try to access the site is an exception.  "**ServiceNotFoundException: The service "security.authentication.manager" has a dependency on a non-existent service "security.user.provider.concrete.fos_userbundle".**"

I based my modifications on [This Cookbook Recipe](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html)

Any ideas?  I am thoroughly stumped on this.

Comment: Well I was able to get the changed name of the provider to function, because I forgot to update the provider in the firewalls/main/form_login section.  Now the login process is working exactly the same as if I made no changes, and the provider I specified is not being called.  I was able to verify it was not being called by dropping an echo and an exit command in the constructor.

Comment: Well I was able to solve it.  I am not able to answer my question for 8 hours though, so I will mark it solved at that point and post how i solved it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get it to work.  Turns out I needed to make the "id" the same as the name of the service I was using.  The commented lines are the originals that came with the bundle.

```
security:
    providers:
        me.security.authentication.userprovider:
            id: me.security.authentication.userprovider
        #fos_userbundle:
            #id: fos_user.user_provider.username
```